# Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Principal'. Cannot convert value "" to type "Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance"

Tags: windows, powershell, task

I am trying to create a scheduled task in Powershell which will run a job that uses the active desktop.

1) is my assumption correct that a scheduled task can see the active desktop when it runs?

2) When I execute the following poweshell script, I keep getting an error:   Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Principal'. Cannot convert value "Servername" to  type "Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance"

The code is below:

```
import-module PSScheduledjob

$TaskStartTime =  (Get-Date).AddMinutes(2) 
$TaskName = "ExecTestCase"

write-output $TaskStartTime

$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "C:\Selenium_Ruby\framework\run_locally_but_update_from_PROD_first.bat"
$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -At $TaskStartTime -Once
$principal = "servername\userid"  #assume servername \ userid is in quotes
Register-ScheduledTask BatchRunTask -action $action -principal $principal -trigger $trigger
```

What is wrong?
Also sometimes I get an access denied for the scheduled task too

thanks

Comment: `$principal = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserId "servername\userid"`?

Answer (score 2):

The parameter `-principal` does not accept `string` input.
Refer to [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/new-scheduledtaskprincipal?view=win10-ps).

Example:

```
$STPrin = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -GroupId "BUILTIN\Administrators" -RunLevel Highest
```